# How to use external JS libraries in MEAN JS app

Tags: mean-stack

I am building a webapp using MEAN JS. I need to use [TypedJS](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) for providing a text animation. How to use this js library. I tried to add typed.min.js to Config->ENV->all.js file. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need is .

1. Add the typed.js to bower.json like this

   ```
     "dependencies": {
           "bootstrap": "~3",
           "angular": "~1.2",
           "angular-resource": "~1.2",
           "angular-mocks": "~1.2",
           "angular-cookies": "~1.2",
           "angular-animate": "~1.2",
           "angular-touch": "~1.2",
           "angular-sanitize": "~1.2",
           "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
           "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1.1",
           "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.11",
           "typed.js": "latest"
       }
   ```
2. run `bower install`  to install the dpendencies
3. add the typed.js and jquery in the all.js

   ```
   js: [
   'public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
   'public/lib/typed.js/dist/typed.min.js',
   'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
   'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
   'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js', 
   'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js', 
   'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js', 
   'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
   'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
   'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
   'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'
   ]
   ```

jquery will already installed but need to add in the all.js.

Actually this worked for me.